# Rails 4 Controller for Reviews Create method is passed all the correct parameters however it does not create properly

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-4.2

*********SOLUTION********
<%= f.hidden_field :property_id, :value => @property.id %>
the hidden field was not properly assigned to f which failed to pass to the controller. Thank You Steve Klein

---

I am currently working on a website where people can post and review properties.
I'm running Ruby 2.2.0 and Rails 4.2.3.

I currently have a property class that also displays reviews belonging to that class. There is also a simple create view interface rendered through a partial form. The Review Create method needs

1. description
2. user_id
3. property_id

The create method properly receives through the params the :description and :user_id however the property_id is not being properly assigned. The validations in review.rb accepts the description and user_id but not the property_id.

1. Property.find_by_id(params[:id]).id
   In the _review_form.html.erb
2. @property.id
   In the show.html.erb

both correctly return the id of the current property in the views.

Can Anyone see what I'm doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
              belongs_to :property
              belongs_to :user
              default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
              validates :user_id,       presence: true
              validates :property_id,   presence: true
            end

class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
      before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]

      def create
        #Errors out @review = Review.build(review_params) Review.build method does not exist
        #@review = current_user.reviews.build(review_params)
        @review = Review.new(review_params)
        @review.user_id = current_user.id
        @review.save
        if @review.save
          flash[:success] = "Review created!"
        else
          flash[:failure] = "Try Again"
        end
        redirect_to :back

      end

      def destroy
      end

      private

        def review_params
          params.require(:review).permit(:description, :property_id)
        end
    end


class CreateReviews < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :reviews do |t|

      t.text :description
      t.references :property, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.references :user, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_index :reviews, [:user_id, :created_at]
    add_index :reviews, [:property_id, :created_at]
  end
end
```

```html
    <!--Applicable Code in properties/show.html.erb-->
    <% if logged_in? %>
      <div class="row" style="width:25% centered">
          <section class="review_form">
            <!-- @property.id correctly returns the id of the current property -->
            <%= render 'shared/review_form', locals: {property_id: @property.id} %>
          </section>
      </div>
    <% end %>
```

```html
<!-- properties/show.html.erb -->
    <% provide(:title, @property.title) %>
      <!-- PROP TITLE -->
      <div class="centered">
        <h2><%=@property.title.upcase%></h2>
        <h4><%=@property.address_street %></h4>
        <h4>Owned by <%=@property.user.name%></h4>
      </div>
    <% form_for @property,  :url=> {:action=> (@property.new_record? ? 'index' : 'new')} do |f| %>

    <% end %>
    <!-- PUTTING IN THE SLIDER -->
      <div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">          
        <div class="item"><%= image_tag "lroom1.jpg" %></div>
        <div class="item"><%= image_tag "lroom2.jpg" %></div>
        <div class="item"><%= image_tag "room1.jpg" %></div>
        <div class="item"><%= image_tag "room2.jpg" %></div>
        <div class="item"><%= image_tag "room3.jpg" %></div>
      </div>
    <!-- DESCRIPTION TABLE -->
    <div style="background-color:#F8F8F8; padding-top:30px ">
    <table class="descrip centered">
      <tr >
        <td>Description</td>
        <td class="col-content"><%=@property.summary %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>The place</td>
        <td class="col-content">Has <%=@property.num_bedroom %> beds</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td class="col-content">Has <%=@property.num_bath %> bathroom</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Owner</td>
        <td class="col-content"><%=@property.title %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Address</td>
        <td class="col-content"><%=@property.address_street %></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br />

    <div>
    <h1> Hello World <%= Property.find_by_id(params[:id]).id%> </h1>

    <!--<body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;" onload="initialize()">-->
    <table class="centered reviews">
      

      <% @reviews.each do |d| %>
        <tr>  
        <td>
          <%= image_tag d.user.image %>
          <p ><%= d.user.name %></p>
        </td>
        <td class="col-content">
            <p>Contact at <%= d.user.email %><br /><br />"<%= d.description %>"</p>
        </td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
      
    </table>

    <% if logged_in? %>
      <div class="row" style="width:25% centered">
          <section class="review_form">
            <!-- @property.id correctly returns the id of the current property -->
            <%= render 'shared/review_form', locals: {property_id: @property.id} %>
          </section>
      </div>
    <% end %>






    <%= javascript_tag do %>
      window.address = '<%= j @property.address_street %>';
    <% end %>

     <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text"
            placeholder= "<%=@property.address_street %>" >
     <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:500px;"></div>

    </div>



    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
     
      $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
     
          autoPlay: 3000, //Set AutoPlay to 3 seconds
     
          items : 4,
          itemsDesktop : [1199,3],
          itemsDesktopSmall : [979,3]
     
      });
     
    });
    </script>
```

```html
  <!-- partial form _review_form.html.erb -->
  
  <%= form_for(@review) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="centered">
   <h1> Property ID is <%=Property.find_by_id(params[:id]).id%>
   </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :description, placeholder: "Create A Review" %>
  </div>
  <!-- Property.find_by_id(params[:id]).id correctly returns the id of the current property -->
<!-- The Following Line Returns The Error Message Below-->
  <%= hidden_field_tag(:property_id, property_id) %> 
  <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Error Message: undefined local variable or method `property_id' for #<#:0x007fbc03fcf820>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing `size: @property.id` in your locals when you render the review form but then you are not using `size`.  The `@property` instance variable in the view is not going to be available in the partial.  Also, not sure why you are calling this variable "size".

So, in your main view, replace `<%= render 'shared/review_form', locals: {size: @property.id} %>` with `<%= render 'shared/review_form', locals: {property_id: @property.id} %>`.  In your partial, replace `<%= hidden_field_tag(:property_id, Property.find_by_id(params[:id]).id) %>` with `<%= hidden_field_tag(:property_id, property_id) %>`.

Comment: Hello @steve klein, I thank you for the help. 

The size: @property.id was a mistake from previous attempts to correctly get the create method to work.

 1. Property.find_by_id(params[:id]).id
    In the _review_form.html.erb
 2. @property.id
    In the show.html.erb

both correctly return the id of the current property in the views. So in the _review_form.html.erb the first line of code should have worked. 

When I attempt your fix I get the error "undefined local variable or method `property_id'"

Do you see any other errors? Do you know how I could fix the above error?

Comment: In your post, you updated your main form, so I see you are passing `property_id` to your partial, so it should be in scope there.  Can you update your partial in your post to show it being used there and indicate which line of code is erroring?  Also, please confirm that you are not calling this same partial from somewhere else.

Comment: I have updated the code above along with the error message it presents ->

undefined local variable or method `property_id' for #<#:0x007fbc03fcf820>. An important detail that I have realized is that even when the correct property_id was set, the controller still could not create the review because the property_id would remain nil and would not pass the presence true validation. Thank you hope to hear from you soon

Comment: So is `@property.id` nil or populated in the main view (`show`)?  From your comments, it looks like it is populated properly, even up to the call to render the partial.  If so, is `property_id` in the partial not getting set to the same value as `@property.id`?

Comment: @property.id in the show.html.erb is populated correctly. Within the partial form property_id is an undefined local variable or method `property_id'. Within the partial, both :property_id and @property.id are nil.

Comment: OK I think I might have it.  If you use `:locals`, you need to also use `:partial`.  So, change the call `<%= render 'shared/review_form', locals: {property_id: @property.id} %>` to `<%= render partial: 'shared/review_form', locals: {property_id: @property.id} %>`.  I usually leave `:locals` off, so I forgot about this issue.

Comment: @property.id, property_id, and Property.find_by_id(params[:id]).id all populate correctly within the partial form after the fix suggested above. Unfortunately when the form is submitted and the review is created, the property_id is still set to nil and fails validation. I believe the problem is within the create method.

Comment: Does the `params` hash include the correct `property_id`?  How about `review_params`?  If those look good, you can always just try `@review = Review.build(review_params)` and then set `@review.user_id` manually before saving.

Comment: After printing the params passed to Controller Create, only description is passed. The property_id is not properly passed from the partial form. How would we go about sending the property_id to the Create Controller along with the description?

Comment: Can you see the hidden field set correctly in your browser (using Firebug or a similar tool)?  Also, how is `@review` getting set in your partial?  Anything you need in your partial needs to be sent in your locals hash or generated there (e.g. `review = Review.new` - although it is better to limit logic in your views).

Comment: Thank You Steve. It appears that the hidden field was not set correctly. This line is the correct line. <%= f.hidden_field :property_id, :value => @property.id %> I forgot to set the field to f which then failed to pass it to the controller

Comment: Glad you figured it out.